# node.js: Return from function not acting as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm very new to javascript/node.js and I'm having trouble with the following code. This is the handler for API an call. The 2nd code segment is just like the 1st, except there is an additional database lookup Merchant.findOne(...), and therefor the 'newTransaction.save()' function is nested one level deeper.

Both code segments return the 'output' variable value correctly. However, the second code segment does NOT also properly save the 'newTransaction' to the Mongo database.

I'm pretty sure the issue has to do with how/when the code returning from newTransaction.save(function (err, transaction){..} but I can't seem to get it straightened out.

I have been looking all over the internet trying to understand and fix this, with no success. Any help is appreciated...

Here is the older, simpler code that works as expected:

```js
 handler : function(request, reply) {

        var output = {
            "success": true,
            "operations": [],
            "epoch": Date.now()
        };


        Terminal.findById(request.payload.deviceNumber, function (err, terminal) {
            if (err) {
                return reply(Boom.internal('Error looking up terminal.', err));
            }
            if (terminal) {

                ticket.quote("bitstamp", "USD", 1, function (err, exchangeRate) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        return reply(Boom.internal('Error obtaining ticket quote.', err));
                    }

                  var newTransaction = new Transaction({
                        terminal: request.payload.deviceNumber,
                        merchant: terminal.merchant,
                        ccExchangeRate: exchangeRate.buy,
                        fiatAmtDue: request.payload.transactionValue,
                        ccAmtDue: ccAmtDueTruncated
                    });

                    newTransaction.save(function (err, transaction){
                        if (err) {
                            return reply(Boom.internal('Error creating new transaction.', err));
                        }

                        output.operations.push(
                            {
                                "control": "KeyPairGenControl",
                                "rand": cc.pseudoRandomBytes(32).toString('hex'),
                                "follow": {
                                    "url": "/pos/v1/AddressAndEncKey",
                                    "post": {
                                        "transactionId": transaction.transactionId
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        );

                        return reply(output);

                    });

                });
            } else {
                return reply(Boom.internal('Error looking up terminal.', err));
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the new code that does NOT save the newTransaction data into the Mongo DB.

```js
handler : function(request, reply) {

        var output = {
            "success": true,
            "operations": [],
            "epoch": Date.now()
        };


        Terminal.findById(request.payload.deviceNumber, function (err, terminal) {
            if (err) {
                return reply(Boom.internal('Error looking up terminal.', err));
            }
            if (terminal) {

                Merchant.findOne({merchantId: terminal.merchant}, function(err, merchant) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('Cannot find merchant');
                        return reply(output);
                    }
                    var processor = merchant.backendPaymentProcessor.name;
                    var localCurrency = merchant.localFiatCurrency;
    //###################
                    ticket.quote(processor, localCurrency, 1, function (err, exchangeRate) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err);
                            return reply(Boom.internal('Error obtaining ticket quote.', err));
                        }

                        var newTransaction = new Transaction({
                            terminal: request.payload.deviceNumber,
                            merchant: terminal.merchant,
                            ccExchangeRate: exchangeRate.buy,
                            fiatAmtDue: request.payload.transactionValue,
                            ccAmtDue: ccAmtDueTruncated
                        });

                        newTransaction.save(function (err, transaction){
                            if (err) {
                                return reply(Boom.internal('Error creating new transaction.', err));
                            }

                            output.operations.push(
                                {
                                    "control": "KeyPairGenControl",
                                    "rand": cc.pseudoRandomBytes(32).toString('hex'),
                                    "follow": {
                                        "url": "/pos/v1/AddressAndEncKey",
                                        "post": {
                                            "transactionId": transaction.transactionId
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            );

                            return reply(output);

                        });

                    //return reply(output);

                    });
    //###################
                });
            } else {
                return reply(Boom.internal('Error looking up terminal.', err));
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I did a diff of your 2 version:

[image]

### Check 1

**ticket.quote**

- Callback are identical for both version
- `processor`, `localCurrency` are different

  1. Is `exchangeRate` pass into callback correct?

### Check 2

**newTransaction.save**

- `newTransaction` and callback for .save are setup identical

  1. Check(console.log()) the values used in setting up `new Transaction({...})`
  2. Check `transaction` object received by callback
  3. Check/debug the code of Transaction.save().

I don't think the issue is with the code you posted. Both version reached `return reply(output);` inside newTransaction.save's callback. Very likely issue is inside Transaction class or Transaction.save() logic.

One scenario I can think of is when a transaction failed:

1. Transaction object is available (even for failed transaction)
2. Transaction Class / Transaction.save() does not write to db because transaction failed
3. Transaction.save() pass `transaction` object to callback, but NOT setting `err`, even when it should.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose having a feature to specify the collection name under the schema, or as the third argument when declaring the model. Otherwise it will use the pluralized version given by the name you map to the model.

**Mongoose official doc having following statement:**

Mongoose by default produces a collection name by passing the model name to the utils.toCollectionName method. This method pluralizes the name. Set this option if you need a different name for your collection.

> **schema-mapped:**

```
new Schema({ <key>: <value>}, 
       { collection : '<collection name>' });   // collection name
```

> **model-mapped:**

```
mongoose.model('<Model name>', 
           new Schema({ <key>: <value>}), 
           '<collection name>');     // collection name
```

[You may also find same here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection)